# Why the FastText word embedding could generate the representation of a word from another language?

Tags: python, gensim, word-embedding, fasttext, nlp

Recently, I trained a FastText word embedding from [sentiment140](https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140) to get the representation for English words. However, today just for a trial, I run the FastText module on a couple of Chinese words, for instance:

```
import gensim.models as gs

path = r'\data\word2vec'

w2v = gs.FastText.load(os.path.join(path, 'fasttext_model'))

w2v.wv['哈哈哈哈']
```

It outputs:

```
array([ 0.00303676,  0.02088235, -0.00815559,  0.00484574, -0.03576371,
       -0.02178247, -0.05090654,  0.03063928, -0.05999983,  0.04547168,
       -0.01778449, -0.02716631, -0.03326027, -0.00078981,  0.0168153 ,
        0.00773436,  0.01966593, -0.00756055,  0.02175765, -0.0050137 ,
        0.00241255, -0.03810823, -0.03386266,  0.01231019, -0.00621936,
       -0.00252419,  0.02280569,  0.00992453,  0.02770403,  0.00233192,
        0.0008545 , -0.01462698,  0.00454278,  0.0381292 , -0.02945416,
       -0.00305543, -0.00690968,  0.00144188,  0.00424266,  0.00391074,
        0.01969502,  0.02517333,  0.00875261,  0.02937791,  0.03234404,
       -0.01116276, -0.00362578,  0.00483239, -0.02257918,  0.00123061,
        0.00324584,  0.00432153,  0.01332884,  0.03186348, -0.04119627,
        0.01329033,  0.01382102, -0.01637722,  0.01464139,  0.02203292,
        0.0312229 ,  0.00636201, -0.00044287, -0.00489291,  0.0210293 ,
       -0.00379244, -0.01577058,  0.02185207,  0.02576622, -0.0054543 ,
       -0.03115215, -0.00337738, -0.01589811, -0.01608399, -0.0141606 ,
        0.0508234 ,  0.00775024,  0.00352813,  0.00573649, -0.02131752,
        0.01166397,  0.00940598,  0.04075769, -0.04704212,  0.0101376 ,
        0.01208556,  0.00402935,  0.0093914 ,  0.00136144,  0.03284211,
        0.01000613, -0.00563702,  0.00847146,  0.03236216, -0.01626745,
        0.04095127,  0.02858841,  0.0248084 ,  0.00455458,  0.01467448],
      dtype=float32)
```

Hence, I really want to know why the FastText module trained from [sentiment140](https://www.kaggle.com/kazanova/sentiment140) could do this. Thank you!

Comment: How was your FastText model trained? (What parameters, etc?) Does the `sentiment140` dataset include any Chinese characters?

Comment: @gojomo Thanks for your feedback! For the parameter selection, I use the following settings: FastText(size=100, window=3, min_count=1, iter=10)
I think the Sentiment140 currently only contains the English and Spanish tweets based on this link:https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sentiment140/7RdUMLgCDrY

Comment: Can you search the actual file you're using for training for characters like `哈`? If they're present, that would be one way to explain your results. (Alternatively, if character encodings are confused in any way, perhaps fragments of the multibyte encoding of `哈` have become ngrams in the model. To consider this possibility, what Python version are you using?)

Comment: @gojomo Thanks for your prompt reply! I am using Python 3.5 now. I just checked the sentiment140 dataset and found that there is no '哈' in any tweets....Is it possible that when generating the representation for the word  '哈', the model actually computes the representation for the Unicode of this word  '哈', which is actually nonsense?

Comment: If there's no other explanation, that might be possible... but unlikely. However, I just looked through the `training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv` file inside `sentiment140.zip`, and there is at least one `哈` character. I'm not sure that one can explain your results, but are you sure you're looking at the right training data? Are you sure your generically-named `fasttext_model` file was only trained on `sentiment140` tweet text? (What is the size of the model's vocabulary?)

Comment: Note that the eventual proper behavior of Gensim should make this question moot – see the answer I've just posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, the proper behavior for a FastText model, based on the behavior of Facebook's original/reference implementation, is to *always* return a vector for an out-of-vocabulary word.

Essentially, if none of the supplied string's character n-grams are present, a vector will still be synthesized from whatever random vectors happen to be at the same lookup slots in the model's fixed-size collection of n-gram vectors.

In Gensim up through at least 3.7.1, the `FastText` class will throw a `KeyError: 'all ngrams for word _____ absent from model'` error if none of an out-of-vocabulary word's n-grams are present – but that's a buggy behavior that will be reversed, to match Facebook's FastText, in a future Gensim release. (The [PR to correct this behavior has been merged](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/pull/2370) to Gensim's develop branch and thus should take effect in the next release after 3.7.1.)

I'm not sure why you're not getting such an error with the specific model and dataset you've described. Perhaps your `fasttext_model` was actually trained with different text than you think? Or, trained with a very-small non-default `min_n` parameter, such that a single `哈` appearing inside the `sentiment140` data is enough to contribute to a synthesized vector for `哈哈哈哈`?

But given that the standard FastText behavior is to always report some synthesized vector, and Gensim will match that behavior in a future release, you shouldn't count on getting an error here. Expect to get back an essentially-random vector for completely unknown words with no resemblance to training data.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I just checked the sentiment140 data again. I just downloaded the dataset directly from the website mentioned in the question. I read the data directly using pandas. The 'encoding' when reading the CSV file is 'Latin-1' since Unicode decode error occurred when using 'UTF-8'. Then I just use a for loop and for each tweet, I check whether a character '哈' is in there...I still can't see any '哈' appeared in sentiment140
But thanks for your answer! Waiting for the newest version of Gensim！

Comment: I see line 350183 of the file `training.1600000.processed.noemoticon.csv` from `sentiment140.zip` as `"0","2017601504","Wed Jun 03 08:39:21 PDT 2009","NO_QUERY","leona0909","Reading: 我們都是???馬???.... @ 哈囉～ 馬凌諾斯基 URLNOTSHOWN)"`. So, there may be an aspect of encoding issues to your problem.

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your answer!